# Divisors of n! including 1 which sum to n!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I believe that given any positive integer $n$, we can find a set of divisors of $n!$, including $1$, which sum to $n!$ I checked for the first 6 positive integers, and tried to prove it by induction on $n$. However I was unable to formalise the proof, can anybody present a method of proving this? Or maybe without induction?

Comment: $x$ trivially divides itself and sums to itself, so you may want to clarify this some.

Comment: @user669545 The question is about divisors of $n!$, not divisors of $n$.

Comment: For example, 3!=6=1+2+3, and 4!=24=1+2+3+6+12 so the claim holds for some $p>2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by induction. For $n=3$, you already observed that $1+2+3$. Now take $n>3$, then $(n-1)!$ is sum of some of its divisors, with $1$ included among them. By multiplying this equality by $n$, you'll get sum of divisors of $n!$, summing to $n!$, and the smallest of them is $n$. Now we can just put $1+(n-1)$ instead of $n$ and we're done.

Comment: +1 And this yields $n!=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k!}n!$.

Comment: That's a very nice argument:)

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{n!}{2}+\frac{n!}{3}+\frac{n!}{6}=n!$ works for all $n\ge 6$

Comment: Indeed, but this doesn't contain the divisor $1$. Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: You require that the sum contain $1$? As stated in your question, it just appears as though you are saying that $1$ counts as a divisor of $n!$. Please clarify that in your question if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Write $n!=2 \times \prod_{k=2}^{n-1}(1+k)$, then expand the product to get a subset of the divisors of $\frac{1}{2}n!$. Now you just need to multiply each term by $2$. Since you want one summand to be one, you should split at the end the least term greater than two in $1+(x-1)$. By the restriction 'greater than two' the other summand will be unique in the sum.

Comment: Take a closer look at the case that the expansion gives some term multiple times, but I think that should not be hard to solve.